# Possessive with acronyms

Tags: possessives, possessive-s-vs-of

Can the possesive formulation apostrophe s be used with acronyms of institutions. For instance: NASA's maps?

Are institutions treated as person names, or differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not treated differently. The possessive form of the apostrophe applies to an acronym as elsewhere. The acronym forms a proper noun.

Comment: Could you provide a reference, or some sort of recognisable example?

Comment: @ Luis: No. Sometimes people just know things, like that capitals must be used for the start of sentences. The OP can take or leave the information or do their own research. I am just trying to help the person with a quick (and accurate) answer to their question. Every time I ask a question, I try to help someone else with what *I* know. I understand that that irritates the admin here no end, but it probably doesn't irritate the person looking for an answer. Not every question needs an encyclopaedic response!

Comment: Ok, thanks. The issue would be if someone else come up with an alternative answer, a in that case a reference would back yours. But since the question was closed that risk no longer exists.